# Validating primary key uniqueness

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a table for which I need to check that there are no fault entries that do not abide to the primary key that runs over 2 columns.

I am kinda stuck trying to write a SQL query to do this. As in, I would not know where to even begin.

Does any of you know how I can write a SQL query that checks whether there are any duplicate entries in a table for a combination of column X and Y?

Comment: GROUP BY. HAVING. COUNT()

Comment: If two columns are declared as a primary key, then there is no need to validate uniqueness.  The database does that for you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff unless you get a data set that claims the uniqueness and is full of hidden trash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get duplicates in two columns using:

```
select x, y
from t
group by x, y
having count(*) > 1;
```

This is unnecessary if `(x, y)` is declared as a primary key.  Duplicate values cannot be inserted into the table with this declaration.

In SQL Server, this is also true if `(x, y)` is declared as unique.  In some databases, `null` values are allowed to be duplicated with a `unique` constraint/index; however, SQL Server does not allow duplicate `NULL` values for unique constraint/indexes.